# Incorrect htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm using the following code, but it's displaying incorrectly.

Error: There is currently an extra **"/"** in front of the domain name and **"[QSA,L]"** after the domain name.
Hoping someone can help me now.

```
add_action( 'init', 'mdv_add_rule' );
function mdv_add_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'demo/(.+)$', 'https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]' );
}
```

[image]

***Thank you for watching***

Comment: `add_rewrite_rule` is probably not meant for this kinda stuff, but for local rewrites only. Looks like it expects the second parameter to always be a local path, that would explain why it prefixes the / on its own. And using the QSA and L flag would also make sense for those kinda rewrites. If you don't have a specific reason why this absolutely needs to be done from within code, then you are probably better off by adding the necessary RewriteRule to your .htaccess file manually.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the interest and reply, I need to do it this way in the main htaccess section to avoid the case when using the "options-permalink" setting they will be removed.

Comment: Just remove the extra `/` and replace your flags with `[R=301,QSA,L]` in the RewriteRule line . You can also remove the `QSA` flag because it's not needed there as your rule appends the query strings automatically.

Comment: @AmitVerma I'm looking for a way to remove it according to my code, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to do it this way in the main htaccess section to avoid the case when using the "options-permalink" setting they will be removed.

To avoid the directives being removed/overwritten when resetting permalinks in WordPress you simply add the directives at the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section.

Any external redirect should go before any of the WordPress rewrites anyway (including before that `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` directive).

You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive, since that is already included in the WordPress section that occurs later in the file. (If you have multiple `RewriteEngine` directives then the *last* instance wins and controls the entire file.)

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation, I have applied in htaccess to process faster, less complicated.

One more thing I learned from you "RewriteEngine On" doesn't have to do so many repetitions of this.

I'm using multiple repeats of "<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>" . Do I need to remove them like "RewriteEngine On".

Comment: @DucPhuli You're welcome. You can remove the additional `<IfModule>` wrappers. (But don't touch the directives in the `# WordPress` section.) You would only need the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrappers if the directives are optional and you are using the same config on multiple servers where mod_rewrite might not be installed. See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/112602/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters stack: [Is Checking For mod_write Really Necessary?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112600/is-checking-for-mod-write-really-necessary)

Comment: Ok thanks. I will read more later, if there's anything I don't understand, I hope to get more answers.